SFML on XCode (MacBook Air M2)
I want to work with SFML on my Mac on Xcode. I read this thread: How do I use SFML on Apple M1 Mac? and I am trying to install SFML same way as someone did this in first answer. I have also installed Rosetta. But I have some issues with that.
First, I tried to do this the same way:
g++ /Users/'myname'/Documents/projects/'myproject'/'myproject'/'myproject' -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1_1/include -o app -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1_1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

ld: warning: search path '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1_1/lib' not found

ld: library 'sfml-graphics' not found

clang: **error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

And the files were not found, so I looked it up carefully and I saw that my files are "2.6.1" not "2.6.1_1" so I tried this:
g++ /Users/'myname'/Documents/projects/'myproject'/'myproject'/'myproject' -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include -o app -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

ld: file cannot be mmap()ed, errno=22 path=/Users/'myname'/Documents/projects/'myproject'/'myproject'/'myproject' in '/Users/jessicapawlowska/Documents/projects/'myproject'/'myproject'/'myproiject''

clang: **error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

And this also didn't work. How to fix that? I really want to work with SFML on Xcode.

Do you really have a file called /Users/'myname'/Documents/projects/'myproject'/'myproject'/'myproject'? Three myprojects? Also if you are programming C++ then your source files should end in .cpp, so g++ something.cpp

Yes, I did stupid mistake and I didn't add cpp at the end, thank you. Now everything worked ok on the console, but when I wrote code from the comment in this previous thread I still have error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found

So according to the compiler options you have there should be a file called /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp. Do you have that file?

Yes, I've got it. When I'm compiling it on the console with g++ everything is working, but my Xcode still doesn't see this and I have a lot of errors

Unfortunately I know nothing about XCode.
